# In Cypress, how do I use the scrollIntoview() function when the default scrolling element is not scrollable?

Tags: ionic-framework, scroll, cypress

The ionic app I'm testing makes it so Cypress's default scroll attempt does not work. The only way I can actually scroll is by targeting a specific element like:

```
cy.get('ion-content').shadow().find('main').scrollTo('bottom')
```

Attempts to scroll with more generic methods such as 'cy.scrollTo('bottom')' are met with the error:

**Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.scrollTo() failed because this element is not scrollable:

Make sure you're targeting the correct element or use {ensureScrollable: false} to disable the scrollable check.**

So my question is, does this mean I am unable to ever use

```
cy.get('element').scrollIntoView()
```

My understanding is that the 'scrollIntoView()' method attempts to scroll using the default scrolling element, which doesn't work for the ionic app I'm testing. Is there a way to make 'scrollIntoView()' scroll using a specific scroll element?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to scroll using the x and y axis ? 'cy.scrollTo(x, y)'

Comment: Also, are you trying to scroll to the bottom of the page or is this a dropdown menu or something like that ?

Comment: cy.scrollTo(x, y) does nothing (regardless of the x and y values provided), and I'm trying to simply scroll down the page as a whole.

Comment: Have you tried `cy.scrollTo('bottom', { ensureScrollable: false })` ?

Comment: Same, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was to set the focus inside the ion-content for example by clicking on an element inside the ion-content then the `.scrollIntoView()` worked.